# how to cofirm fmt lib version info?

Tags: fmt

how to cofirm fmt lib version info?

I'm using the format.h and format.cc files at work, but I don't know how to check the version of the format.h format.cc in use. Is there a way to find out what version it is through the code that exists in format.h and format.cc ?

Answer (score 2):

The [`FMT_VERSION`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/baae1ed65855796055d226571ac5ca376266914d/include/fmt/core.h#L21) macro defined in `fmt/core.h` gives you the version:

```cpp
// The fmt library version in the form major * 10000 + minor * 100 + patch.
#define FMT_VERSION 100101
```